# Aplicativo Android encerra-se ao mudar de Paisagem para retrato

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

Criei um app android simples, com Jquerymobile, sem nada demais, apenas pages e listview.

Se ele iniciar no modo Paisagem, funcionara apenas assim, caso o usuário mude o Smartphone de posição, o app fecha automaticamente, e ocorre o mesmo com o modo paisagem.

Não entendo o porque deste comportamento.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>

<style type="text/css">
      h2 
      {
       text-align: center;

         }


     h4 
      {
       text-align: center;

         }
     img 
     {
         height: auto;
         width: auto;
         }   
</style>
    </head>
    <body > 


      <div data-role="page" id="one">

    <div data-role="header" style="background-color:#E0FFFF">
        <h1> </h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" >  
        <h2><b>Quem Somos</b></h2>

        <p>A   &   é uma ótima oportunidade para pessoas que querem ganhar um dinheiro a mais. A empresa de venda social permite às mulheres ter seu próprio negócio 
        de moda ao tornar-se uma estilista, a qual é responsável pelas vendas das joias da marca. <br />
        Os produtos são exclusivos, com características finas e delicadas, e elaborados por profissionais com mais de 10 anos de mercado, que fazem com total zelo e 
        dedicação a produção e finalização dos itens. Com a qualidade incomparável dos acessórios, será fácil vendê-los para familiares, amigas, conhecidas e 
        até mesmo em lojas virtuais e redes sociais – nas quais a divulgação é ainda mais prática e eficiente. <br />
        O papel da estilista é auxiliar a potencial compradora a escolher as joias da marca que mais realçarão sua beleza. As vantagens de tornar-se uma são 
        inúmeras: a própria vendedora determinará seu horário de trabalho, quanto quer ganhar, a forma de abordagem às clientes e muito mais.<br />
        Além disso,   &   disponibiliza ferramentas online para ajudar a estilista a conquistar clientes fiéis e oferece 50% de desconto para adquirir os 
        primeiros itens.<br />
         O lucro vem de maneira rápida: com um investimento inicial de R$ 199,00, em até 6x, a mulher recebe um mostruário com valor total sugerido 
        de R$ 500,00. Além da renda extra obtida ao fazer parte do negócio de joias   &  , a estilista terá grandes recompensas pessoais, como reconhecimento 
        profissional, diversão ao trabalhar com algo prazeroso, autonomia para realizar as vendas, flexibilidade de horário e conquista da independência financeira. <br />
        Sem dúvidas, ser uma parceira de negócios da   &   traz muitas vantagens para a <b>Mulher Moderna!</b></p>




    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="d" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tendencias" >Tendências</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#two" data-transition="turn">Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page one -->


<!-- Start of second page: #two -->
<div data-role="page" id="tendencias" >

    <div data-role="header" style="background-color:#E0FFFF">
        <h1>Tendências</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" >  
        <h4>Fique por dentro das tendências, siga as nossas dicas e arrase em seu Look</h4>




        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Procure artigos" data-inset="true">
                    <li><a href="#artigo1">Terminologia das Pedras</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Banana</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cherry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cranberry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Grape</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Orange</a></li>
        </ul>



    </div><!-- /content -->



    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#one" data-transition="turn">Pagina 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#two" data-transition="turn">Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page two -->


<!-- Start of third page: #popup -->
<div data-role="page" id="popup">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
        <h1>Dialog</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="d">    
        <h2>Popup</h2>
        <p>I have an id of "popup" on my page container and only look like a dialog because the link to me had a <code>data-rel="dialog"</code> attribute which gives me this inset look and a <code>data-transition="pop"</code> attribute to change the transition to pop. Without this, I'd be styled as a normal page.</p>      
        <p><a href="#one" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="back">Back to page "one"</a></p> 
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="persistent">
        <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page popup -->










<!-- Tendências -->
<div data-role="page" id="artigo1" >

    <div data-role="header" style="background-color:#E0FFFF">
        <h1>Carnaval da Sofie</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" >  
        <h2>TERMINOLOGIA DAS PEDRAS</h2>
        <p>

        A valorização de uma pedra pode vir de sua raridade, beleza pela cor, a um fenômeno óptico exclusivo, brilho diferenciado, além da dureza e inclusões exclusivas e únicas.
        O termo gema geralmente refere-se a uma pedra já lapidada, algumas  das características que valorizam as  gemas só se apresentam depois da pedra estar lapidada.
        A terminologia constantemente utilizada é de suma importância ser compreendida para não ocorrer duvidas sobre as pedras utilizadas na composição de uma joia.
        Abaixo vemos as lapidações mais utilizadas.

        </p>

       <picture>

            <img src="imagens/terminologiadaspedras.jpg" alt="pedras"/>
    </picture>

    </div><!-- /content -->



    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#one" data-transition="turn">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tendencias" data-transition="turn">tendencias</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page two -->







    </body>



            <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


        <link href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, possivelmente é porque você não está **tratando** a orientação de seu app.

Tem uma resposta bem simples, são somente 2 passos, porem o texto está em inglês. [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806938/is-there-a-way-to-force-horizontal-landscape-layout-on-mobile-devices).

Qualquer coisa, traduzo para você.

Comment: Não funcionou, coloquei a função, chamei ela no onload da pagina e nada.